# Array.pop() returns undefined for non-emty array

Tags: javascript

**Code**

```
console.log("before .pop()");
console.log(this.selectorWindows);
var selectorWindow = this.selectorWindows.pop();
console.log(selectorWindow);
```

**Output**

```
before .pop()
[37: Object, 38: Object, 39: Object, 41: Object, 42: Object, 43: Object, 44: Object, 47: Object, 48: Object, 49: Object, 51: Object, 52: Object, 53: Object, 56: Object, 57: Object, 59: Object, 60: Object, 62: Object, 63: Object, 64: Object, 66: Object, 67: Object, 68: Object, 70: Object, 71: Object, 74: Object, 75: Object, 76: Object, 78: Object]
undefined
```

**Expected ouput**

```
before .pop()
[37: Object, 38: Object, 39: Object, 41: Object, 42: Object, 43: Object, 44: Object, 47: Object, 48: Object, 49: Object, 51: Object, 52: Object, 53: Object, 56: Object, 57: Object, 59: Object, 60: Object, 62: Object, 63: Object, 64: Object, 66: Object, 67: Object, 68: Object, 70: Object, 71: Object, 74: Object, 75: Object, 76: Object]
78: Object
```

How can `.pop()` return `undefined` if there are objects in the array? There is no asynchronous code, which could modify `this.selectorWindows` while using `.pop()`.

Comment: Your array looks weird - why does it start at element `37`?

Comment: Array is different, i mean it's looks like an array of object but it isn't!

Comment: `Array.prototype.pop` will never return `undefined` if the array is not empty.

Comment: @Tresdin `[undefined].pop()`?

Comment: Notwithstanding what I said above, there is nothing wrong with starting an array at element 37. And `pop` should still work just fine (https://jsfiddle.net/4mtvy8u8/) We need steps to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @undefined Oops, I've forgot that.

Comment: @undefined now we know how you got your username :)

Comment: can I ask you how you have declared your array or from where it comes?

Comment: `There is no asynchronous code, which could modify this.selectorWindows`,  Even if you did have some asynchronous code, it couldn't modify it anyway.

Comment: I know it's pseudo notation, but FWIW, `pop` won't return `78: Object`, just `Object`.

Comment: I used the array (var this.selectorWindows = []) as an associative array, and added my elements like this.selectorWindows[id] = {}, which is obviously not working. My bad guys.

Comment: What does `console.log(this.selectorWindows.length)` give you?

Answer (score 4):

If that's really an Array, then the latest element is `undefined` (I know that was commented already). Arrays consider any type of values in their sequence, this always depends on its native length. If the latest element is `undefined` it's still part of the length

There are some ways to get the last valid value (and remove it if you want) though:

- If you want objects you can filter each element of that array and copy those which are objects. Then you can call Array#pop normally, but you can get `undefined` if the Array is empty;
- You can do a loop that begins at the end and ends at the start of that array, making it stop when your wanted element is found;
- And etc...

---

For instance

```
arr = this.selectorWindows
var arr, i, item

for (i = arr.length; --i >= 0;) {
    item = arr[i]
    if (item instanceof Object) {
        arr.splice(i, 1)
        break
    }
}

// Now check if the latest item got in loop is an
// object

if (item instanceof Object)
    // Use it
```

Or you can filter that array:

```
arr = this.selectorWindows
var arr

filtered = arr.filter(value => value instanceof Object)
var filtered

// Now call Array#pop
filtered.pop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a sparse array, i.e. an array with many `undefined` values in it. `pop()` essentially returns (and removes) `arr[arr.length - 1]`. If your array's `length` property (minus 1) points to an element which is `undefined`, that's what you'll get.

Comment: Where's the solution

Comment: Take care that your array values are in sync with its `length`…?

Comment: Then comment it

Comment: OP mostly asks *why*. A specific solution is hard to come up with without more context. But providing the reason for *why* it doesn't work as expected will probably help OP develop a solution for themselves.

Comment: But this is a comment, anyway. Your answer doesn't provide a solution. Someone already downvoted me for this same reason, so I'm sure... Mine perfect answer to a question had the same objective as this, and there was many chars and they downvoted me

Comment: I hope you're not just downvoting me in retaliation…

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an array as an associative array, use an object `var myobject = {}`

It's not a good Idea to fill an array with `myarray[i] = myValue` because you don't have item between the others, that's why you got `undefined`

Example : 
```
   var a = [];
   a[2] = 'foo';
   a.length => 3;
   a[30] = 'bar';
   a.length => 31
   a[78] = 'buzz';
   a.length => 79;

var b = a.pop();
   b => 'buzz';
   a.length => 78
   a[77] => undefined;

```

Between a[30] and a[78] javascript fill the array with undefined values;
That's why you got `undefined`

Then if you want to use an array correctly, push objects into the array or use a map object `{}`
And if you want to remove the object with the higher id, create a function or use an array in the side, that contains id and you sort the array to get the lastest id that is the highest.

Answer (score -2):

This could be an array-like structure. It only includes the `.length` property and access through indexes, but it doesn't include `.pop()`.
There is the `Array.from` method which could be used to transform your object into an array.

```
let selectWinArray = Array.from(this.selectorWindows);
```

See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Comment: If that was the case a console error would have shown there was no `pop` method - it wouldnt have just magically returned undefined

Comment: The array like object could have an `.pop()` in its prototype. Yes it is improbable, but that's why I included an "this could be".

Comment: An malfunctioning `.pop()`